# yii2 retrieve passwordHash for AccessTokenByUser

Tags: yii2

for use in Mobile App, I am trying to use Yii2 built in RestApi.
Now what I understand by the reading that we should disable session and set loginUrl property to false.

Now what I want is, I want a login screen for my app and want to authenticate against API.
how I can achieve the same.

Note:
I can authenticate with username and password for different controllers including users controller as well as bearer token.

also I read an example in" yii2 by example"

```
public function actionAccessTokenByUser($username, $passwordHash)
        {
            $accessToken = null;

            $user = \app\models\User::findOne(['username' => $username, 'password_hash' => $passwordHash]);
            //var_dump($passwordHash1);exit;
            if($user!=null)
            {
                $user->access_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
                $user->save();
                $accessToken = $user->access_token;
            }        
            return [ 'access-token' => $accessToken ];
        }
```

my question is how I get the `$passwordHash to supply here. I tried to look back and forth, but couldn't find any solution.

my main purpose is how I can implement a application login for mobile and thereon supply the `accesstoken` in the background wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have refactored the code to achieve what I am looking. Open to suggestion or any flaw in my implementation.

here is what I have done.

```
public function actionAccessTokenByUser($username, $password)
        {
            $accessToken = null;      
            $username = \app\models\User::findByUsername($username);
            if ($username!=null) 
            {
              if($username->validatePassword($password)) $user = $username;
            }   

          //  $user = \app\models\User::findOne(['username' => $username, 'password_hash' => $passwordHash]);

            if($user!=null)
            {
                $user->access_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
                $user->save();
                $accessToken = $user->access_token;
            }        
            return [ 'access-token' => $accessToken ];
        }
```

Comment: It looks ok-ish as long as you don't need that token expiring and so on. Take a look at OAuth2 authorization, there are some packages for Yii 2 that will do all that for you. And you might want to verify that `$user->save()` result in case it's false.